# How to include only definitions from header

Tags: c, linux, macros, posix, flags

I'm implementing right now some syscalls from unistd.h and fcntl.h (open, read, close, e.t.c)
Some of the require special flags and macros (O_CREAT, O_RDWR)

Is there a way to include only the flags and macros without the function definitions
from unistd.h and fcntl.h?

Thanks

Comment: If it's only for a test, you could edit the 2 files and surround the function prototypes by `#ifdef DONT_INCLUDE_PROTOTYPES ... #endif`.

Comment: I don't want to edit the header files. Is there any other way?

Comment: What is the motivation for this?

Comment: You could copy the files to myunistd.h and myfcntl.h in your source-dir and then include them with `#include "myunistd.h"` after editing. Can you explain, what you're trying to do at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `-imacros` option to `gcc` is what you are looking for.

> `-imacros FILE`
>
> ```
>  Exactly like `-include`, except that any output produced by
>  scanning FILE is thrown away.  Macros it defines remain defined.
>  This allows you to acquire all the macros from a header without
>  also processing its declarations.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Generally - no. If you look at the headers in question, you'll see that no prototypes are surrounded by definitive macroses, which will just exclude them.

You might manage to get *some* of the definitions by including sys/types.h, stddef.h and the like, but not all of them.

All the function prototypes are declared "extern", BTW, and as such should be no obstacle to your implementation.